# VS code intellisense is not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Trying to get Intellisense working in VS code. I know it should work out of the box (for my friend it does), but it is not doing that for me. Problem is that the typescript properties are not loading in the HTML file when pressing ctrl+space. Any suggestion?
Setup:
 - Vs code version: 1.15.1 (latest stable version).
 - Windows 10.

[image: serverStatus property from component template are not loading in the list]

[image: Here is the component and its two properties (serverId and serverStatus which are supposed to load]

Top picture: 'serverStatus' property from component template are not loading in the list.

Second picture: Here is the component and its two properties (serverId and serverStatus which are supposed to load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a library for angular to get this to work. Typescript doesn't have any template engine in its core. This is an angular thing. So its the right default behaviour.

You can checkout a plugin like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

They should help you with your needs.